# jQuery dropdown menu getting hide while using scroll bar

Tags: jquery

I am working on a language dropdown menu. Only one issue, can we stop hiding the dropdown menu while using the scroll bar inside the dropdown? Menu is getting hide when I click on Up/Down Arrow or Scroller.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/BwcS8/

jQuery

```
 $(function() {
//hide menu if we click any where on the page
var menuClicked = false;
$(document).on('click', function(){
    if(menuClicked){
        menuClicked = false;   
        return;
    }
    if($(".add_language_menu_item").css('display') != 'none'){
        $(".add_language_menu_item").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    }
});
//open menu if we click on Add More Languages menu
$(".add_language_menu").each(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find(".add_more_languages").length > 0) {
        $(this).mousedown(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).attr('type') == 'checkbox') return;
            $(this).find(".add_language_menu_item").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
            menuClicked = true;
        });          
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified our code little bit:

```
    $(".add_language_menu").each(function(e) {

    if ($(this).find(".add_more_languages").length > 0) {

            if($(e.target).attr('type') == 'checkbox') return;
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).find(".add_language_menu_item").slideToggle();
            menuClicked = true;
            });
     }});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwcS8/3/)**

Comment: I tried but it's not working. Maybe I am putting the line in wrong place. Where should I add this line, can you please guide?

Comment: add it to child click events.

Comment: Sorry, I am not good in jQuery. Can you please let me know exactly from which line should I add e.StopPropagation();